# on scrolling screen to a particular how do you hide the tab bar in an app bar

Tags: flutter, tabbar

working on whatsapp clone app and i want to remove tab bar and appbar when i scroll to camera screen. please how do i go about it thank i really appreciate.

this is my code below.

```
return DefaultTabController(length: 5, child: Scaffold(
    body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
      return <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: Text("WhatsApp",style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontSize: 22.0,
          ),),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 117,94,1),
          actions: [
            IconButton(onPressed: null, icon: Icon(Icons.wifi,color: Colors.white,size: 30,)),
            IconButton(onPressed: null, icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidMoon,color: 
Colors.white,)),
            IconButton(onPressed: null, icon: Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.white,)),
            IconButton(onPressed: null, icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert,color: Colors.white,)),
          ],
          pinned: true,
          floating: true,
          bottom: TabBar(
            indicatorColor:Colors.white,
            indicatorWeight: 3,
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white70,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt, color: Colors.white,),),
              Tab(text: "CHATS",),
              Tab(text: "GROUPS",),
              Tab(text: "STATUS"),
              Tab(text: "CALLS"),

            ],

          ),
        ),
      ];
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tabbar Property onTap, manage a variable to store the current tab index and try condition in this scenario for appbar.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).